# MVC data transfer model to view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model

I'm having some issues with keeping my model data controller to view and view to controller.

I'm building an application which filters exam questions.
The user clicks a button which sends him to a view, in which he put some data.

a [HttpPost] method is invoked.
Using the users data, the app creates a list of question which is being kept in the model. 
The updated model is returned to the same view (using return View(model);), for another data update.
Then the user can click again on the the same button to send the data again to the [HttpPost] method to update the questions list - the big issue here is that the list of questions is not there - the list contains null!
I' using a strong type model and I can see the questions (using the debugger) in the Model in the view...

So please - what an I missing here? How can I keep the models data when moving controller - to - view and view - to contrroler?

any help is most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Every time you return to the view, you will need the viewmodel data with it. My guess is that when the method returns again, the data is not being passed sufficiently.

An example method that loops the data back:

```
public ActionResult Example(Viewmodel obj)
 {

         ...... code that alters any data

    //makes new viewmodel instance to handle return data
    Viewmodel newObj = new Viewmodel();
    newObj = obj; //sets old viewmodel equal to new viewmodel (can be changed in above code using obj)
    newObj = obj;


   return View("MyView", newObj); //returns with viewmodel back
 }
```

Comment: Also I was working a while ago where a method was invoked more than once, and I had to remove the Post from the method, making it reachable even on HttpGet.